# SWIG c++ Java DLL Windows

Tags: java, c++, swig

my problem: creating a java wrapper for a c++ DLL.
I know, there are many articles about this issue but so far no solution for me.
Then problem:
I have java 1.6 up 29 32-bit installed on my windows 7, 64 bit, at C:\java\jdk.
This path is part of path variable (open cmdline anywhere, i can always calls javac...)

I have latest swig, which successfully created python and perl wrappers for my DLL.

When i buld java/class sample with VS2008 - which completes without errors - and try to run the runme.java i get the error:

UnsatisfiedLinkError

-> Native code library failed to load. See the chapter on Dynamic Linking Problems in the SWIG Java documentation for help

the DLL is very simple. Statically linked to runtime libs (/MT). No dependecies but still
getting this error.

Please note: the swig sample does not work. Java installed. Also the tcl sample does not work.
tcl 8.4 installed (similar error).

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your class has been compiled successfully, and the native library has been compiled successfully. The issue is that the Java code needs to load, at runtime, the shared object which you generated with Visual Studio.

Try passing `-Djava.library.path=<directory containing your DLL>` when you run the class.

Comment: Hello,thank you for answer. I am java novice. All .java , all .class and the dll are located in the same directory. I run all from command line and just tried a simple java class loading a another dll; just load (loadLibrary(dllname) ). this worked. It must somehow related to swig as the swig own sample fails.

Comment: @user947604: SWIG produces two pieces of code: a C++ file, and a Java file. You compile the C++ file into a DLL. Then you compile the Java file into a .class. Finally, you run the Java class - but the DLL you built must be in the `java.library.path`.

Comment: java jdk is installed at c:\java\jdk. can you tell how to find out where this path is located ?

Comment: @user947604 You set the `java.library.path`. Try running `java -Djava.library.path=. MyClass` When you're in the directory containing the VS-compiled DLL and your Java `.class` file.

Comment: did so. java -Djava.library.path=. MyClass causes same error: "can't find dependent libraries". java -Djava.library.path=.MyClass (without space) causes this error:usage java.... hopefully i did right. MyClass contains a main a static load of library..?

Comment: when i delete the DLL from path, i get java error: "no mydll in java.library.path"   when i put back this simple dll (which does not load any other dll and is statically linked to all libs), i get error: "can't find dependent libraries".  if you install java and swig, you should be able to reproduce this

Comment: must apologize. however, perhaps other can use this information: i have a windows 7 64 bit. when i open a cmd window, it is always 64 bit. installing java 64 bit and building the swig sample x64 (include 64 bit java header) it works.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of what you've described it seems like you've not loaded the DLL you compiled within Java before trying to call one of the (generated by SWIG) JNI methods.

I normally use something like:

```
%pragma(java) jniclasscode=%{
  static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("module");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load. \n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
%}
```

in my SWIG interface file to cause the DLL to be loaded automatically at runtime by the Java code.

(You'll need to make sure the DLL is placed somewhere appropriate with respect to library paths on your system).